# Integration Example

Tags: integration

How can i find the integration of this example
$$\int \frac{\sin x}{\sin x - \cos x } dx$$
I tried first add cos and then substracting cos but then what about $$\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x - \cos x } dx\ ?$$

Comment: You can try $t = \tan (x/2)$, so that $$ \cos x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \quad \text{and} \quad \sin x = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}.$$ Or, you may multiply $\cos x + \sin x$ to both numerator and denominator and utilize double-angle of sine and cosine.

Comment: the ans. in my book will not match when i take t=tan(x/2) or convert it into double angle Is there any easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply and divide Numerator by 2 to get $2\sin(x)$ and write it as $(\sin(x)+\cos(x)) + (\sin(x)-\cos(x))$ then divide each term by denominator.Second term would be 1(you can integrate it easily),for first term,  put $(\sin(x)-\cos(x))$ as $z$ then, $(\sin(x)+\cos(x))dx$ would become $dz$ and your first integral will look like $\int {\frac{dz}{z}}$, which is $ln(z)+c$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(a) = \int \frac{\sin(ax)}{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}dx$.
Differentiating throughout by a, we get
$$f'(a) = a\int \frac{\cos(ax)}{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}dx$$
Therefore, $$af(a) - f'(a) = a\int \frac{\sin(ax) - \cos(ax)}{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}dx$$
Substituting $a = 1$, we get
$$f(1) - f'(1) = x + C_1$$
Also,
$$af(a) + f'(a) = a\int \frac{\sin(ax) + \cos(ax)}{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}dx$$
Substituting $a = 1$ gives,
$$f(1) + f'(1) = \int \frac{\sin(x) + \cos(x)}{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}dx = \ln(\sin(x) - \cos(x)) + C_2$$
The integral was simply solved using the substitution $t = \sin(x) - \cos(x)$.
Solving the above two equations for $f(1)$ gives,
$$2f(1) = x + \ln(\sin(x) - \cos(x)) + C_1 + C_2$$
Therefore,
$$f(1) = \frac{1}{2}(x + \ln(\sin(x) - \cos(x)) + C_1 + C_2)$$
which is what we sought.

Comment: Above I demonstrate how you nail a toothpick with a big hammer :-D

Comment: 1+ for the big hammer :D

Answer (score 1):

Now let 
$$ I = \int \frac{\cos x}{\cos x + \sin x} \, \mathrm{d}x \quad \text{and} \quad J = \int \frac{\sin x}{\cos x + \sin x} \, \mathrm{d}x$$
Notice that 
\begin{align*}
I + J & = \int \frac{\cos x + \sin x}{\cos x + \sin x} \, \mathrm{d}x = x + \mathcal{C} \\
I - J & = \int \frac{(\sin x + \cos x)'}{\cos x + \sin x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \ln\bigl( \cos x + \sin x \bigr) + \mathcal{C}
\end{align*}
Solving the system yields
$$I = \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}\ln\bigl( \cos x + \sin x \bigr) + \mathcal{C}$$
and
$$J = \frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{2}\ln\bigl( \cos x + \sin x \bigr) + \mathcal{C}$$
as wanted.